# 2003 Putnam A-1 Help needed about sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, analysis, contest-math

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer. How many ways are there to write $n$ as a sum of positive integers, $$n = a_1 + a_2 +\dots + a_k$$ with $k$ an arbitrary positive integer and $a1 \le a2\le ...\le a_1 + 1$? For example, with $n = 4$, there are four ways: $4, 2+2, 1+1+2, 1+1+1+1$.

---

Okay so for $n=1$ there is only one way. For $n=2$ you have, $1+1, 2 + 0$ for $n=3$ you have: $1+1+1, 1+ 2, 3 + 0$ three ways.

So $P(n): n$ ways, we must prove the $P(n+1): n + 1$ statement is true.

How do we do so is the question?

Can I have **hints only?**

Comment: Can you see how you might get the two ways to represent $2$ from the one way to represent $1$? How about the three ways to represent $3$ from the two ways to represent $2$? (aka try to figure out how an induction statement might work in these concrete low-number cases first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: As an alternative to an inductive approach: for each possible choice of $k$ (the number of terms), there is exactly one  choice of $a_1$ that allows the inequalities to be satisfied and the sum of the $a_i$’s to be $n$.

Comment: Great answer as always BrianM.Scott. Up vote well deserved. Can I ask a question ? Can you please elaborate on what you mean by exactly one choice of a_1? Excellent answer.

Comment: @Amad27: As an example, suppose that you want $3$ terms that meet the conditions and sum to $7$. Clearly $2+2+3$ works. Suppose that we try to start with $1$: the biggest the other two terms can be is $2$, and $1+2+2$ is only $5$, so that won’t work. And if we try to start with $3$, the smallest we can manage is $3+3+3=9$, so that won’t work, either. Thus, for $n=7$ and $k=3$ the only possible value of $a_1$ is $2$. Moreover, the other two numbers have to be $2+2$, $2+3$, or $3+3$, and only one of those adds up to the missing $5$, so $2+2+3$ is the only solution with $k=3$. It turns out ...

Comment: ... that this idea generalizes. A lot.

Comment: I found a solution here: http://inside.mines.edu/~dlarue/putnam/exams/2003s.pdf    I am. Of sure what they are doing. Also, how can a_1 < ... < a_1 + 1 ?? This would mean all a_k between the above are fractions? Can you please explain what they are trying. Thank you BrianMScott, for all assistance you have given here!

Comment: @Amad27: You’re welcome! Take a closer look: those inequalities are all $\le$, not $<$, just as in the statement of the problem. In fact, that solution is the one that I was hinting at in my answer and in the example in the long comment.

Comment: But how does they get from: $a_1 \le a_2 \le a_3 \le ... \le a_k \le a_1 + 1$ to $ka_1 \le n$ how is the inequality true? Thank you!

Comment: @Amad27: Remember that $n=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_k$. Since $a_1$ is the smallest of the $k$ terms, $$n=a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_k\ge\underbrace{a_1+a_1+\ldots+a_1}_{k\text{ terms}}=ka_1\;;$$ does that help?

Comment: I understood this, thanks. can you assist my question here by any chance? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124980/how-does-this-person-solve-the-putnam-problem/1124985 It is about the **same Putnam** question but a diffeent sub-question.

Answer (score 2):

For a given positive integer $n$, let $p_i(n) = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k)$ be a given partition of $n$ that satisfies the criteria.  For each such partition $p_i(n)$, how many ways are there to generate a unique partition $p_i(n+1)$?  Is there a bijection?

Comment: Can you describe more about bijection? Unique partitions? I would greatly appreciate it! (+1)!!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you had for n = 2 the solutions as 1+1, 2+0 but 2+0 cannot be a solution based on the problem constraints.

Edit: My bad, as I was working through 2+0 did not make sense but 2 is clearly a solution. But I was able to prove this by thinking for each n, how many ways can you sum to n with k numbers (knowing the largest possible k is k =n where all the terms are 1. Example for n=5, k=3 there is only one possible way 1+2+2.

Comment: $n = 2$ still has two solutions: $2 = 2$, $2 = 1+1$. You are correct in that $2 + 0$ does not work, though.

Comment: And $n=3$ has $3$ solutions: $1+1+1$, $1+2$, and $3$.

Answer (score 0):

The given partitions $(a_1, \dots, a_k)$ are all given by
\begin{align*}
a_i &= \begin{cases}
a_1 & \text{if $i \leq p$}; \\
a_1 + 1 & \text{if $i > p$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for $p = 1, \dots, k$. Count the number of pairs $(a_1, p)$ for which the partition sums to $n$.