# How does this person solve the Putnam problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Consider this: [2003 A1 Putnam Solution.](http://inside.mines.edu/~dlarue/putnam/exams/2003s.pdf)

I am only looking at A1 for Putnam 2003.

The problem is here: [Problem A1 2003](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~dale/putnam/2003.pdf)

I would like to proceed step-by-step:

I understand $ka_1 = a_1 + a_1 + ... + a_1$ step easily.

I also see why $ka_1 < n$ because $a_1 + a_1 + a_1 + ... < a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ...$

I also see:

$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + .. < a_1 + (a_1 + 1) + (a_1 + 1) + (a_1 + 1)$

Where all $\sum a_1 = ka_1$. but how do they get: the $k - 1$ part there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where they write
$$
a_1 + (a_1 + 1) + (a_1 + 1) + \cdots + (a_1 + 1) = ka_1 + k - 1
$$
is that what you're wondering about? Because $a_1$ is written $k$ times, and $1$ is written $k-1$ times (after each of the $k$ instances of $a_1$, except the first one), so that's what it becomes. Clearer ways of writing the right-hand side in that respect include $k(a_1 + 1) - 1$ and $k\cdot a_1 + (k-1)\cdot 1$.

Comment: +1, after that, what do they do finding a unique integer?