# Solving the Sequence of this question on Putnam Exam

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

Problem:

[image]

Solution: [Solution for 2003 A1 Putnam](http://inside.mines.edu/~dlarue/putnam/exams/2003s.pdf)

$ka_1 = a_1 + a_1 ... a_1 \le n \le a_1 + (a_1 + 1) + (a_1 + 1) ... (a_1 + 1)$

$= ka_1 + k - 1$

I know these then:

What should I do next? Without knowing the answer?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123754/2003-putnam-a-1-help-needed-about-sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $ka_1\le n\le ka_1+k-1$. This is where some experience helps: I would see $ka_1+k$ and immediately think $k(a_1+1)$, making the whole thing

$$ka_1\le n\le k(a_1+1)-1\;.$$

That means that $\frac{n}k$ is trapped between consecutive integers:

$$a_1\le\frac{n}k\le a_1+1-\frac1k\lt a_1+1\;.$$

And that's exactly what it means to say that $a_1=\left\lfloor\frac{n}k\right\rfloor$, so $a_1$ is uniquely determined by $n$ and $k$: once we know them we know the only possible value of $a_1$.

Since $a_1$ has to be positive, this tells you that $1\le k\le n$, and your next (and last) step is to try to show that for each $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ there is exactly one solution. (By having gathered some numerical data initially, you would already suspect that there should be $n$ solutions altogether.)

Comment: Brian M. Scott, as always your answer is great! +1.  I want to see the $\frac{n}{k}$ being trapped. So: $ka_1 \le n \le k(a_1 + 1) - 1$ then we have: $a_1 \le \frac{n}{k} \le a_1 + 1 - \frac{1}{k}$ Like you said. But what does it help to show $a_1$'s value?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ping you. Thanks for your help here I appreciate it!

Comment: @Amad27: You’re trying to count solutions for a given $n$. The part of the argument given above shows that for each $k$ from $1$ through $n$ there is at most one possible starting term $a_1$. Experimentation with small values of $n$ suggests that there’s probably exactly one solution for each of these possible values of $k$, and now we know what it has to start with. The rest of the argument, then, should be showing that there actually *is* exactly one set of $k$ integers, all of them either $a_1$ or $a_1+1$, that adds up to $n$.

Comment: I dont get what $k$ even means here? $a_k \le a_1 + 1$ I believe. then the solution somehow puts in $i$ without replacing the $k$ is $ka_1$?

Comment: Also how do you have $k$ possibilities for the sum? As described in their solution?

Comment: @Amad27: Suppose that $k=4$ and $a_1=2$; then $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$ must be one of the sums $2+2+2+2$, $2+2+2+3$, $2+2+3+3$, and $2+3+3+3$. The last $i$ such that $a_i=2$ can be $4,3,2$, or $1$. The same thing happens in general: the first term has to be $a_1=\lfloor n/k\rfloor$. It’s possible that all $k$ terms are equal to $a_1$, in which case the $i$ of the solution is $k$; it’s possible that $a_1=\ldots=a_{k-1}$, but $a_k=a_1+1$, in which case the $i$ of the solution is $k-1$; and so on, down to $i=1$, when $a_2=\ldots=a_k=a_1+1$. That’s $k$ possibilities, since $i$ can be anything from ...

Comment: ... $1$ through $k$. These $k$ possible sums are $k$ consecutive numbers covering the range from $ka_1$ through $ka_1+k-1$, and $n$ is in that range, so exactly one of them is equal to $n$. Thus, each $k$ from $1$ through $n$ gives rise to one solution, and there must therefore be $n$ solutions.

Comment: Brian M. Scott, I cannot thank you enough! You must be a great professor!  There is a doubt though. It is said that (in the solution): the sum is equal to $ka_1 + (i -1)$ Where $i \in \{ 1, ... k \}$ The trouble I am having is how is the SUM = $ka_1 + (i -1)$ doesnt the solution itself earlier state: $a_1 + (a_1 + 1) + (a_1 + 1) + ... + (a_1 + 1) = ka_1 + k - 1$

Then this implies $a_k = (a_1 + 1)$ for all $k$?